# SQlite allows auto increment creation of a primary key referencing another table

Tags: sqlite

I have those two tables implementing some inheritance relationship via the [Class Table Inheritance pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html):

```
pragma foreign_keys = ON;
create table foo(foo_id integer primary key);
create table bar(foo_id integer primary key references foo(foo_id));
```

Let's populate `foo`:

```
insert into foo values (1), (3), (4);
```

Now I can insert `3` into `bar`:

```
insert into bar values(3);  -- no error
```

I cannot insert `2`:

```
insert into bar values(2);  -- Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

However, what suprises me is that `NULL` values can be used to generate new keys:

```
insert into bar values(NULL); -- OK, 4 inserted
insert into bar values(NULL); -- FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

This behavior seems rather odd. When I try the same thing in MySQL, I am greeted with a

```
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'foo_id' cannot be null
```

which is what I would expect.

I find this behavior particularly dangerous when inserting new rows in `bar` with a subquery:

```
insert into bar (foo_id) values ((select foo_if from foo where ...))
```

which could end up silently inserting random rows into `bar` when there is no match in `foo`, instead of returning an error.

Is this behavior compliant with the SQL standard, in what scenario could it be useful, and more importantly, is there a way this behavior could be changed to match MySQL's?

**EDIT**

Here is an illustration of the problem in a perhaps more striking (and scary) fashion:

```
pragma foreign_keys = ON;

create table people(people_id integer primary key, name text not null);
insert into people (name) values ("Mom"), ("Jack the Ripper");

create table family_member(people_id integer primary key references people(people_id));

insert into family_member values ((select people_id from people where name = "Mom"));
insert into family_member values ((select people_id from people where name = "Dad"));  -- silent error here

select name from family_member inner join people using (people_id);
-- uh-oh, Jack the Ripper is now part of my family
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I found an anwer to this problem, which may be a bit surprising for people not familiar with SQLite.

It turns out that a column that is declared `integer primary key` is automatically filled with an unused integer if it is not given a value.

A somewhat arcane way around this in SQLite is to use declare the column `int primary key` instead, which prevents the implicit automatic handling.

However, we are not over yet, because another distinctive behavior of SQLite is to allow `NULL` primary keys -- in our example above, `insert into bar values (NULL)` *would* insert a new row with a `NULL` primary key.

To explicitely ban primary keys from having `NULL` values, it must be declared not null:

```
pragma foreign_keys = ON;

create table foo(foo_id integer primary key);
create table bar(foo_id int primary key not null references foo(foo_id));

insert into foo values (1), (3), (4);

insert into bar values (3);
insert into bar values (2);  -- Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
insert into bar values (NULL);  -- Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: bar.foo_id
```

This is probably the way primary key pointing to external keys should be declared by default in SQLite.

Comment: Everything that you find surprising or arcane is described in the link I provided: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html and also mentioned  in my answer: *because foo_id is defined as integer primary key which means that it is also AUTOINCREMENT* and also *Don't use a primary key that is auto increment to reference another primary key that is also auto increment.* This is how SQLite works. You did not know that. You got an answer that mentioned all of that. And now you posted an answer?

Comment: My answer gives the solution to my problem. The link you provide does not (only the "integer primary key" special behavior, not even the work around it). Your answer is even worse, by not giving an answer and instead saying the question is wrong, because Class Table Inheritance is wrong. Your answer is not helpful and even misleading. Get over it and move on.

Comment: Your answer doe not give a solution to anything. This is neither a solution nor a workaround. It is bad design. If you work with such a design, sooner or later you will realize it. Also start reading the documentation (the link I provided).